# Jquery array loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I am attempting to loop through the contents of an array in Jquery, the array contains a list of Place Names, followed by a URL ([0]name, [1]url, [2]name [3]url, etc.). The data for place names has been pulled through an API and as such some are undefined. Below is my loop in its current iteration.

> ```
>       for (var i=0; i<albums.length; i++){
>             if ((albums[i] != "undefined") && (albums[i+1].indexOf("http") !== 1)){
>                 $("#thumbnail").css("overflow:", "auto");
>                 $("#thumbnail").css("max-height:", "100px");
>                 $("#thumbview").append('<div id="thumbnail"><img src='+[i+1]+' id="coverPhoto" height="320" width="420"></a></div>');
>             }
>             i++;
>         };
> ```

Below is the array as it is structured currently

> Array[14]
>
> [0]:"location name"[1]:"https:/..."[2]:"location name"[3]:"https:/..."[4]:"location name"[5]:"https:/..."[6]:"location name"[7]:"https:/..."[8]:undefined[9]:"https:/..."[10]:undefined[11]:"https:/..."[12]:"location name"[13]:"https:/..."

My goal for the loop is to check [i], if [i] is NOT undefined,  then check [i+1] to see if it contains "http", if both conditions are true > build the image with the source from the array, and set the name and caption as location name.

in its current iteration it doesn't seem to be working correctly, it just iterates through and builds the div regardless of whether the name is undefined or not.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `i+1` will cause trouble in `last-iteration`..

Comment: Can you share the following - structure of array, input, output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually checking if the content of albums[i] equals the string undefined.
You should check if the content of albums[i] is undefined.
You should also use the `===`/`!==` operators. If you want to check if the variable is null you should then check if `albums[i] === null` or `albums[i] !== null`

`albums[i] != "undefined"` => `albums[i] !== undefined`

Here is your for loop :

```
for (var i = 0; i < albums.length; i++){
    if ((albums[i] !== undefined) && (albums[i+1].indexOf("http") !== 1)){
        $("#thumbnail").css("overflow:", "auto");
        $("#thumbnail").css("max-height:", "100px");
        $("#thumbview").append('<div id="thumbnail"><img src=' + [i+1] + ' id="coverPhoto" height="320" width="420"></a></div>');
    };
};
```

Comment: IMO, `albums[i] !== "undefined"`

Comment: @Jean-Paul_Goodwin, There is still double incrementing right? `for (var i=0; i<albums.length; i++){` and `i++;` or doesn't this matter?

Comment: @Roy_Dorsthorst Yes, I just removed it. The code will work better and not skip a div

Comment: @Rayon Yes, in fact, you should always use the three equals operator. I just edited the answer.